# idHttp And Https Page Login Error

Tags: delphi, openssl, idhttp

```
procedure TForm1.btnGirisClick(Sender: TObject);
var
post:tstringlist;
get:TStringStream;
begin
post:=TStringList.Create;
get:=TStringStream.Create('');
try
post.Clear;
IdHTTP1.Disconnect;
post.Add('email=xxx@xxx.com');
post.Add('pass=xxxx');
IdHTTP1.Post('https://www.facebook.com/login.php',post,get);
Memo1.Text:=get.DataString;
except
on e: exception do begin
memo1.text:='';
end;
end;
post.Free;
get.Free;
end;
end.
```

i need to help about idHttp and ssl library...

i write a simple delphi7 code (want to login facebook with my application) and when i want to run it , it give me a error the code is below ;

and the error is "Could Not Load SSL Library" i drag a idHttp and IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1 and set iohandler to IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1. what can i do to run the code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have both of the SSL dlls in either your application folder or your system/win32 folder.

Get them here: http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Comment: i did it and the program give me another error. that is "Error connecting with SSL" what is that ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: Make sure you set the method to sslvSSLv23 as well as the IPVersion to id_ipv4.  Also im assuming your using the IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL

Comment: yes i set the method sslvSSLv23  but i use IdSSLIOHandlerSocket i dont find  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL in delphi 7. are they same ?

Comment: No, if you don't have it in the original Indy package that came with Delphi 7 Make sure to either upgrade Delphi or atleast update your indy to the latest

Comment: i solved the problem. thanks for your help. and i ask a question more , how can click login button on the page with idhttp ?

Comment: Do a POST on https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1.
I'm actually trying to login into facebook at the moment too but experience a load of trouble, if you are ever able to please feel free to message me on your ways

Comment: i'm tried to login facebook i used the code above. and facebook give me a error that "Cookies are Required" have any idea ?